# I'm getting an error when I send multiple tables to query with codeigniter active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I tried to add all the tables to the private variable $table so that it returns them after the query but it gives me an error. The error is that it tells me that the table that I put does not exist.
OK so I have:

```
<?php 
class Joins_model extends CI_Model{
    private $table = 'cm_proveedor, cm_compras, cm_valuacion, cm_valuacionr, cm_nomina, cm_empleado';
    function _construc(){
       parent::Model();
    }

    function get_reg($data){
        $this->db->select('
                            cm_proveedor.nombre,
                            cm_valuacion.mano_obra,
                            cm_valuacion.refaccion,
                            cm_valuacionr.refaccion,
                            cm_valuacion.costoHojalateria,
                            cm_valuacion.costoPintura,
                            cm_valuacion.costoMecanica,
                            cm_valuacion.pv_hojalateria,
                            cm_valuacion.pv_pintura,
                            cm_valuacion.pv_mecanica,
                            cm_valuacion.pc_hojalateria,
                            cm_valuacion.pc_pintura,
                            cm_valuacion.pc_mecanica,
                            cm_valuacion.tipo,
                            cm_valuacion.hojalateria,
                            cm_valuacion.pintura,
                            cm_valuacion.mecanica,
                            cm_valuacion.tipo_r,
                            cm_empleado.nombre,
                            cm_compras.precio
                        ');
        $this->db->from('
                            cm_proveedor
                              INNER JOIN cm_compras
                                ON cm_proveedor.id = cm_compras.id_proveedor
                              INNER JOIN cm_valuacion
                                ON cm_compras.id_siniestro = cm_valuacion.id_siniestro
                              INNER JOIN cm_valuacionr
                                ON cm_valuacion.id_siniestro = cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro
                              INNER JOIN cm_nomina
                                ON cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro = cm_nomina.id_siniestro
                              INNER JOIN cm_empleado
                                ON cm_nomina.id_empleado = cm_empleado.id
                        ');
        $this->db->where('cm_valuacion.id_siniestro',$data);
        $this->db->order_by('id','asc');
        return $this->db->get($this->table);

    }

}
?>
```

and I'm getting the error:

Database error: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1103

Incorrect table name 'cm_proveedor '

SELECT `cm_proveedor`.`nombre`, `cm_valuacion`.`mano_obra`,   `cm_valuacion`.`refaccion`, `cm_valuacionr`.`refaccion`,   `cm_valuacion`.`costoHojalateria`, `cm_valuacion`.`costoPintura`,   `cm_valuacion`.`costoMecanica`, `cm_valuacion`.`pv_hojalateria`,   `cm_valuacion`.`pv_pintura`, `cm_valuacion`.`pv_mecanica`,   `cm_valuacion`.`pc_hojalateria`, `cm_valuacion`.`pc_pintura`,   `cm_valuacion`.`pc_mecanica`, `cm_valuacion`.`tipo`,   `cm_valuacion`.`hojalateria`, `cm_valuacion`.`pintura`,   `cm_valuacion`.`mecanica`, `cm_valuacion`.`tipo_r`, `cm_empleado`.`nombre`,   `cm_compras`.`precio` FROM (`cm_proveedor` INNER JOIN cm_compras ON   cm_proveedor.id = cm_compras.id_proveedor INNER JOIN cm_valuacion ON   cm_compras.id_siniestro = cm_valuacion.id_siniestro INNER JOIN cm_valuacionr ON   cm_valuacion.id_siniestro = cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro INNER JOIN cm_nomina ON   cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro = cm_nomina.id_siniestro INNER JOIN cm_empleado ON   cm_nomina.id_empleado = cm_empleado.id, `cm_proveedor`, `cm_compras`,   `cm_valuacion`, `cm_valuacionr`, `cm_nomina`, `cm_empleado`) WHERE   `cm_valuacion`.`id_siniestro` = '6615' ORDER BY `id` asc

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\pits\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: [Try the manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) and look for `$this->db->join()` An odd idea I know, reading the manual, but as a last resort, _give it a go_ After all its a good way of ___learningbyexample___

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to query from multiple tables usign active record class from codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145187/im-trying-to-query-from-multiple-tables-usign-active-record-class-from-codeigni)

Comment: Do you have a table called `cm_proveedor`, it sound like maybe you dont or you spelt it incorrectly

Comment: Yes, i have a table called *cm_proveedor*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('
                        cm_proveedor.nombre,
                        cm_valuacion.mano_obra,
                        cm_valuacion.refaccion,
                        cm_valuacionr.refaccion,
                        cm_valuacion.costoHojalateria,
                        cm_valuacion.costoPintura,
                        cm_valuacion.costoMecanica,
                        cm_valuacion.pv_hojalateria,
                        cm_valuacion.pv_pintura,
                        cm_valuacion.pv_mecanica,
                        cm_valuacion.pc_hojalateria,
                        cm_valuacion.pc_pintura,
                        cm_valuacion.pc_mecanica,
                        cm_valuacion.tipo,
                        cm_valuacion.hojalateria,
                        cm_valuacion.pintura,
                        cm_valuacion.mecanica,
                        cm_valuacion.tipo_r,
                        cm_empleado.nombre,
                        cm_compras.precio
                    ');

$this->db->from('cm_proveedor');
$this->db->join('cm_compras','cm_proveedor.id = cm_compras.id_proveedor');
$this->db->join('cm_valuacion','cm_compras.id_siniestro = cm_valuacion.id_siniestro');
$this->db->join('cm_valuacionr','cm_valuacion.id_siniestro = cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro');
$this->db->join('cm_nomina','cm_valuacionr.id_siniestro = cm_nomina.id_siniestro');
$this->db->join('cm_empleado','cm_nomina.id_empleado = cm_empleado.id');
$this->db->where('cm_valuacion.id_siniestro',$data);
$this->db->order_by('id','asc');
```

...

Comment: Database error: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'cm_proveedor'

Comment: you are probably using this table name `cm_proveedor` twice in your code. Double check your code for this, or give a alias to this table.